# How to create own gradle dependency library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.1, build-dependencies

For developing android applications by using Android Studio, generally we used to add dependencies in `build.gralde` instead of adding jars or libraries. Example given below

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
```

**How to create my own gradle dependency library in Android Studio?**

Comment: You can create module for that.

Comment: Do you need a library module?

Answer (score 10):

I've already created my own library [`CustomSpinner`](https://github.com/piotrek1543/CustomSpinner) and its Gradle's dependency
is

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.piotrek1543:CustomSpinner:0.1'
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this is what you're expecting.

I made it using Jitpack.io and following steps in that great Medium article:

[Create and Distribute your own Android Library after reading this post!](https://medium.com/@zurche/create-and-distribute-your-own-android-library-after-reading-this-post-c3187a2a0691#.f9rq4y8kq)

I don't want copy-paste what was here already said, so please patiently read this article.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your Android library (New project->Android library project), and upload it to bintray.

Answer (score 1):

[JitPack](https://jitpack.io/) is amazing for this. You can very simply make a library you have created available to anyone if it is hosted on GitHub (or other git host) and you add some config stuff Gradle and JitPack want. Have a look [here](https://jitpack.io/docs/#publishing-on-jitpack) at the JitPack publishing docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can different types of dependencies in a project:

```
dependencies {
        // Dependency on the "mylibrary" module from this project
        compile project(":mylibrary")

        // Remote binary dependency
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'

        // Local binary dependency
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
```

Also you can use aar files defining a `flatDir`:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

then adding the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFileWithoutExtension', ext:'aar')
}
```

To create a **library module** just create a module in Android Studio and use in the `module/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Then you can use it as:

- a project (`compile project(":mylibrary")`)
- you can build the aar file and use it as aar file
- upload the library in a maven repository and use it as remote dependency

Comment: we want to create a own gradle dependency file which can be integrated in android studio project . For ex. compile "com.example.myowndepen" like this.